# Allow a list of elements to overflow outside the parent div while maintaining the scrollability of parent on y axis

Tags: html, css

I'm currently working on a list, and it's scrollable on y-axis (`overflow-y: scroll`). I hope when the mouse hover above the list elements, they will scale up and overflow outside the container. However, as the container is now set to `overflow-y: scroll` for the scroll bar, it doesn't allow the children elements to overflow. Basically, I hope to have a scroll bar while allowing child elements to overflow out of the box. Please help.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

ul {
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  /* overflow-y: scroll; */
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 80px;
  border: 1px solid brown;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

li:hover {
  transform: scale(1.3);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul>
    <li>
      Hello
    </li>
    <li>
      Hello
    </li>
    <li>
      Hello
    </li>
    <li>
      Hello
    </li>
    <li>
      Hello
    </li>
  </ul>

</body>
```

Comment: If a child is hovered, is the overflow part supposed to be visible ?

Comment: yep, that's what I hope to achieve, but the scroll bar won't be available, and the elements at the bottom will overflow outside the container which is not what I want.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly your needs, I dont think you can show overflow parts of an element in a `hoverflow:scroll` container.

I think/am convinced that there is a better way to do this, but I leave my attempt here.

Notes :

- It only copy the text of the element, if you have more element, (in line with this attempt) you will probably need to clone ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode)) the hovered element with its children.
- Because on top of the scrollbar and my element is outside the container, it's not easy to scroll

```js
let element = document.getElementById("hoveredElement");

showHoveredElement = (li) => {  
  let offsets = li.getBoundingClientRect();
  element.textContent  = li.textContent;
  element.style.top    = offsets.top + window.scrollY +"px";
  element.style.left   = offsets.left + window.scrollX +"px";
  element.style.width  = offsets.width+"px";
  element.style.height = offsets.height+"px";
  element.classList.remove("d-none");
}

hideHoveredElement = () => {
  element.classList.add("d-none");
}

document.querySelectorAll("li").forEach((li) => {
  li.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
    showHoveredElement(li);
  })

  li.addEventListener("mouseout", () => {
    hideHoveredElement();
  })
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

ul {
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
}

li, #hoveredElement {
  height: 80px;
  border: 1px solid brown;
}

#hoveredElement{
  position:absolute;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  background-color:white;
}
#hoveredElement:hover {
  display:block;
  transform: scale(1.3);
}
.d-none{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    A
  </li>
  <li>
    B
  </li>
  <li>
    C
  </li>
  <li>
    D
  </li>
  <li>
    E
  </li>
</ul>
<div id="hoveredElement" class="d-none"></div>
```